# How can i show ONLY export dropdown and print icon when using Reporting Services URL Access Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, urlaccess

> http://myServer/reportserver?/MyReportsFolder/Report1&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=true

Am using the above URL to display a SSRS report, but i have not liked showing the full report toolbar by setting rc:Toolbar=true. Are there any other parameters i can add to the URL such that when the report displays, only the Export Report Dropdown and the Print Report Icons are displayed on the toolbar. I want to the Zoom, Refresh and all other controls except Export Report Dropdown and the Print Report Icons.

This is easy to set if your using the reporViewer Control, but here am accessing the report directly from its direct URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own Stylesheet. In the Styles folder, copy the file Htmlviewer.css to MyStyleSheet.css, and change the lines

```
.ToolbarZoom
{
    display: inline;
}
```

to

```
.ToolbarZoom
{
    display: none;
}
```

Then reference your stylesheet in the URL: &rc:Stylesheet=MyStyleSheet

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a good solution would be to create an html page with a dropdown and the report format output types and call the same url with the "rs:Format=N" value in the url replaced with the appropriate format.  The print icon could bring up PDF in the browser the user could print.

Otherwise if you are using .Net you can send the report directly to the printer if it is a client or a server report and get all of the other forms of the report in memory and write them out for the user from the application.  But this uses ReportViewer, even if it is never used to render the report, and you said this is not an option.

Using a direct URL I don't think it is possible.  If you want to house it in an iframe, you could set the height and not allow scroll so the report isn't showed to the user.